# 2 jQuery.contextMenu on a page with different trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I have 2 instances of `jQuery.contexMenu` on one page ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JdwxT/593/)). The first one is triggered on right click, the second one on left. When I perform a right click on the first div (without clicking on any menu item), and an other right click on the second div, the second context menu also appears, but it shouldn't. I have the same problem when I start with the second div, with left click...

Comment: Does that happen in the fiddle also? Because it doesn't in my case...

Comment: And why do you have `$(function(){})` twice? Put code inside one them...

Comment: @j809 It does happen in the fiddle too.

Comment: It was an example, I just edited it... The accent is on the appearance, I'll edit the question. You have to perform the second right click just after the first, without clicking on any menu item

Comment: Hmm strange. The mousedown event doesnt show when you entered the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/JdwxT/597/
(open your console to see).

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of transparent wrapper box behind menu. try another plugin. Here is a good example for multiple objects (but no left click trigger) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/200745/jQuery-based-smart-dynamic-popup-context-menu-scri